# Moving code from the view into the LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

So here is the problem I have this query that returns the data for the view

```
reportData = dbContext.FinancialsBySupplierAuditPeriodStatusType
                    .Where(v => v.ReviewPeriodID == reportFilter.ReviewPeriodID && v.StatusCategoryID == reportFilter.StatusCategoryID && v.ClientID == reportFilter.ClientId)
                    .GroupBy(s => new { s.SupplierID })

                    .Select(g => new DrilldownReportItem {
                        SupplierID = g.Key.SupplierID,
                        SupplierName = g.Max(v => v.SupplierName),
                        AccountNo = g.Max(v => v.AccountNo),
                        SuppTotals = g.Select(v => new TempTotals { ClaimType = v.TypeDesc ?? "Old Claims", Amount = v.Amount ?? 0 })
                    }).OrderBy(r => r.SupplierName).ToList();
```

SuppTotals contains an IEnumerable with each of the ClaimTypes in, however they might not contain every single ClaimType if there is no value for that record, so on the view there will be 5 headings but in the table row only two results.

for example there are 5 ClaimTypes but that record has only one of them, this then on the view doesn't allow the headings to match up and data appears blank.

I fixed this issue on the view with this

```
    var existing = i.SuppTotals.Select(x => x.ClaimType);

    var toAdd = Model.ClaimHeadings.Except(existing).Select(x => new TempTotals {
         ClaimType = x,
          Amount = 0
          });

 var row = i.SuppTotals.ToList();
 row.AddRange(toAdd);

 @foreach (var item in Model.ClaimHeadings) {
      <td><span class="text">@String.Format("{0:C0}", row.Where(c => c.ClaimType == item).First().Amount)</span></td>
```

So my question is, is there a way to incorporate this add range into the query itself so that i don't have to put this code in the view and have it in the query.

--Update--

here is the Claim Type Entity

```
  public partial class ClaimType
    {
        [Key][Column(Order = 0)]
        public int ClientID { get; set; }

        [Key][Column(Order = 1)]
        [StringLength(2)]
        //WAS STRING
        public string TypeID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string TypeDesc { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        public char OldTypeID { get; set; }

}
```

and this code pulls all of the claim types with an amount of 0 to add to the ones in report data

```
  var claimTypes = _claimManager.GetClaimTypes(PredicateBuilder.True<ClaimType>().And(x => x.ClientID == reportFilter.ClientId)).Select(x => new TempTotals {
                    ClaimType = x.TypeDesc,
                    Amount = 0
                });
```

Comment: You are speaking about `ClaimTypes`. Where they come from? i.e. do you have some entity (table) or ?

Comment: Claim Types are stored within a table I've updated the question with the entity and the query and the code I use to pull them

Comment: As you are displaying this on a web page, why not use a multi-select checkbox list based on `ClaimTypes` and then check the returned values

Comment: So I guess `v.TypeDesc ` is some sort of a weak link to `ClaimType.TypeDesc`?

Comment: yeah @IvanStoev it is

Comment: @PeterSmith there is a multi select that allows the user to filter the data however it is a requirement for all of the fields to show

Comment: What I am suggesting is that you build the multi-select from the `ClaimType` entity so that it already contains all of them and then, if necessary, check the ones that exist from your query. Separate the multi-select from `reportData `

Comment: @PeterSmith sorry if I'm confusing you or maybe I'm not quite getting what you mean, each record has different claim types so one for example could contain 2 of the 5 record and the next could have 1 of 5 and the next 3 of 5 but they could each be a different selection of the 5 types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the missing claim types to each group by using *antijoin* and `Concat`:

```
SuppTotals = g.Select(v => new TempTotals { ClaimType = v.TypeDesc ?? "Old Claims", Amount = v.Amount ?? 0 })
             .Concat(from ct in dbContext.ClaimType
                     join v in g on ct.TypeDesc equals v.TypeDesc into match
                     from v in match.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where v == null
                     select new TempTotals { ClaimType = ct.TypeDesc, Amount = 0 })
```

Comment: for this throws "
Unable to create a constant value of type 'TempTotals'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Comment: Well, I've tried similar query and it works (EF6.1.3, SqlServer db)

Comment: This was because of something else i had going on, after fixing that it was fine. Cheers